# half size <br /> in my javascript rotating text with fade in

Tags: jquery, css, text-rotation

I built a rotating text with fade in from code i found on the web, i only have a basic code understanding.

quotation[2] needs three lines and others only two, so it moves the site below up and down as it rotates. is there anyway to set a half 
 in this code so i can have a half space above and below the sentence? or to centre the third quote only.

i tried a css with span 0.5em method, but the span wouldnt work inside the rest of this code.

thanks

(site is www.focallocal.org)

```
<DIV id=textrotator style="FONT: 18px arial ; text-align:centre; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: rgb(255,255,255)"></DIV>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0">
  <script type = "text/javascript">
    var hexinput = 255; // initial color value.

    quotation = new Array()
    quotation[0] = "<br />A simple and fun way to make the world and your community a happier, more connected place in your free time<br /><br />" 
    quotation[1] = "<br />Discover how you can shape the world in your spare time through Collective Action<br /><br />"
    quotation[2] = "Bringing people and their communities closer together and dealing with serious societal issues in a constructive, light-hearted, adventurous and enjoyable way"

    function fadingtext()
    { 
      if(hexinput >111) 
      { 
        hexinput -=11; // increase color value
        document.getElementById("textrotator").style.color="rgb("+hexinput+","+hexinput+","+hexinput+")"; // Set color value.
        setTimeout("fadingtext()",300); // 300ms per step
      }
      else 
      {
        hexinput = 255; //reset hex value
      }
    }

 var which = 0;

function changetext()
{
    which += 1; 
    if (which >= quotation.length)
    {
        which = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("textrotator").innerHTML = quotation[which]; 

    fadingtext();

    setTimeout("changetext()",8000);
}

    window.onload = changetext();
  </script></div>
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Comment: thanks for that acfrancis. 

i think the problem is that i cant add any of those codes to that specific line as its displaying the 'quotation' and doenst seem to read any code i put there. i have no idea how i would add it to just the bottom line.